# How to create a second viewport in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, svelte

I have a frontend component which I'd like to put in some HTML element which would act as a second viewport.

Using that, I'd like to emulate how this component looks on, e.g., mobile devices, by resizing that second viewport.

I've heard that an iFrame does the job, but I don't want to use an external website as src, as it's all internal HTML components.

How can I create such a second viewport (so any media queries of the component inside it will trigger when resizing that second viewport as well)? (optimally without an iFrame)

Comment: Apply `resize` css property to `div` and style it as you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: @Zugor oh I think I wasn't clear enough. Making it resizable is not the issue. The issue would be making a second viewport (so media queries for that component would work when I resize it)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any way to scope global `@media` queries other than using a separate window or frame.

The `iframe` element does not need to reference anything external, you can easily just mount a component within a local frame, e.g.

```html
<script>
    import Component from './component.svelte';
    
    function addComponent(frame) {
        const body = frame.contentWindow.window.document.body;
        new Component({ target: body });
    }
</script>

<iframe use:addComponent title="test frame" />

<style>
    iframe { border: 1px solid grey; resize: both; }
</style>
```

The only issue is handling component styles: You have to make sure the component injects its own CSS or add it manually. (If the `css` [compiler option](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-compile) is set to `'injected'`, the styles should be added automatically by the JS.)